# In FME: how to handle NULL values in numeric expressions as 0 using the attribute manager

Tags: fme-form, null, numeric

i stumbled across the following challenge in FME:

how to deal with NULL values if you want to perform a calculation for a new attribute. For example, I want to sum up values (could be any other kind of arithmetics).

The expected result is fine as long as no NULL Value is involved. FME turns any calculation into a NULL result if any NULL is involved ([see documentation](https://community.safe.com/s/article/how-does-fme-handle-null-attribute-values)).

| Result using a numeric expression ---------------------- | Result using a non-numeric expression to illustrate |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The question that haunts me is, how to treat those NULL values as 0 in the calculation without changing the value to an actual 0 (as the NullAttributeMapper would).

The result I am looking for is the following:

If all values are NULL i want the result to be NULL, otherwise I want the NULL value to be treated as 0. Furthermore, I dont want the NULL values to be changed to 0, so I can distinguish between NULL and 0 in further calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AttributeManager has a functionality to handle NULL as 0 (or any other value you like), without tampering with the orignal values.

[image: res0]

The result is what i was looking for:

| Result using a numeric expression in combination with a condition to preserve NULL |
| --- |
| [image: res2] |
| **Result using a non-numeric expression to illustrate** |
| [image: res1] |

Comment: Yes, that's the best way. Another way would be to use a NullAttributeMapper transformer first, assuming you're OK with replacing the values permanently.